# Battery standby

Tags: linux, battery

I am using a lenovo z570 laptop. In windows I  am able to use the laptop for around 2.30 hrs in normal usage.But when I use any Linux distro the battery drains a lot faster. I am able to use only for 40mins or so.where could the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to find out what drains your battery is the `powertop` utility. Powertop will give you a list of the energy consumption of your devices and will show you whether powersaving is enabled or not (and allows you to toggle these settings). 
The `laptop-mode-tools` package (at least that's how it is called in Debian/Ubuntu) can also be helpful in reducing power consumption. In its config file you can specify various settings (e.g. for hard disk spin down) depending on whether the machine is connected to power or running on battery.